# STATIC REGISTER in C optimize time of use alwayse?

Tags: c, static

If we set a STATIC REGISTER variable we can optimize the time of use of the variable as well as keep its value from read to read? its that always true, somtimes ture somtimes not or always wrong?

Comment: For starters, `register` is only a recommendation to the compiler.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [The `register` specifier (...) indicates automatic storage duration.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) I.e., cannot be combined with `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is always wrong because we will get compilation error for using both `static` and `register` for one variable.

[Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rx6V48vMud2ru8Wf):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    static register int i = 0;
    printf("%d\n", i++);
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I got this error:

```
prog.c: In function 'foo':
prog.c:4:5: error: multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers
    4 |     static register int i = 0;
      |     ^~~~~~
```